# Connecting to remote computer using IP adress (VB.net)

Tags: xml, database, vb.net, ip-address

I'm just a hobby programmer so pardon any "Silly" questions I might ask, as I have taught my self as I go.

I have of recent looked into XML databases and would like to know how (if) I could retrieve data in an XML file located elsewhere then on my local computer. I program using vb.net if anyone would like to know.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple, try it with a network-share. Otherwise you would have to install a software on the remote computer to access a normal file. E.g. "Remoting" is a key-word. But it sounds like a normal share would help you. What XML-Database do you have?